# Buddypress Full documentation

Tags: buddypress

I have searched alot for finding the list of Full documentation for buddypress Hooks (action, filtrs) and functions but not satisfied with that limited documentation provided by [Buddypress](http://codex.buddypress.org/home/).

Like if i want to find the detail about **bp_directory_groups_search_form()** there is no specific detail about this mehtod and same for buddypress hook also... So anybody know the exact location of full documentation available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

and here is the almighty output for buddypress 1.5.2!

```
bp_activity_setup_globals
bp_activity_setup_nav
bp_activity_directory_activity_setup
bp_activity_screen_my_activity
bp_activity_screen_friends
bp_activity_screen_groups
bp_activity_screen_favorites
bp_activity_screen_mentions
bp_activity_screen_notification_settings
bp_register_activity_actions
bp_blogs_setup_globals
bp_blogs_setup_nav
bp_blogs_directory_blogs_setup
bp_blogs_screen_my_blogs
bp_blogs_screen_create_a_blog
bp_blogs_register_activity_actions
bp_core_admin_screen_fields
bp_core_admin_screen
bp_adminbar_logo
bp_adminbar_menus
bp_adminbar_random_menu
bp_notification_settings
bp_signup_validate
bp_complete_signup
bp_styles
bp_custom_profile_boxes
bp_custom_profile_sidebar_boxes
bp_core_setup_globals
bp_core_action_directory_members
bp_core_render_message
bp_core_clear_cache
bp_include
bp_setup_root_components
bp_setup_globals
bp_setup_nav
bp_register_widgets
bp_init
bb_admin_footer
bb_admin_head
bb_pre_export
bb_export
bb_admin_notices
bb_schema_defined
bb_get_admin_header
bb_admin_menu_generator
bb_admin_notices
bb_recount_list
bb_admin_notices
clear_auth_cookie
wp_print_scripts
wp_print_styles
bb_ssl_redirect
bb_send_headers
pre_post_form
post_form
post_post_form
bb_admin_notices
bb_options_loaded
bb_underscore_plugins_loaded
bb_plugins_loaded
bb_got_roles
bb_shutdown
bb_init
edit_form_pre_post
post_form_pre_post
bb_got_roles
bb_init
init_roles
bp_forums_setup
bbpress_init
bp_forums_directory_forums_setup
bbpress_init
friends_header_tabs
friends_setup_globals
friends_setup_nav
friends_screen_my_friends
friends_screen_requests
friends_screen_notification_settings
friends_register_activity_actions
bbpress_init
groups_creation_tabs
groups_header_tabs
bp_groups_filter_title
groups_custom_group_boxes
groups_custom_group_admin_tabs
groups_custom_group_fields_editable
groups_custom_group_fields
groups_install
groups_setup_globals
groups_directory_groups_setup
groups_adminbar_menu_items
groups_screen_my_groups
groups_screen_group_home
groups_screen_notification_settings
groups_create_group_step_complete
groups_register_activity_actions
bp_core_loaded
bp_loaded
bp_loader_activate
bp_loader_deactivate
messages_setup_globals
messages_setup_nav
messages_screen_inbox
messages_screen_sentbox
messages_screen_compose
messages_screen_notices
messages_screen_notification_settings
messages_action_view_message
bp_before_404
bp_404
bp_after_404
bp_before_message_meta
bp_after_message_meta
bp_before_message_content
bp_after_message_content
bp_before_activity_loop
bp_after_activity_loop
bp_before_activity_entry
bp_activity_entry_content
bp_activity_entry_meta
bp_before_activity_entry_comments
bp_after_activity_entry_comments
bp_after_activity_entry
bp_before_directory_activity_content
template_notices
bp_before_activity_type_tab_all
bp_before_activity_type_tab_friends
bp_before_activity_type_tab_groups
bp_before_activity_type_tab_favorites
bp_before_activity_type_tab_mentions
bp_activity_type_tabs
bp_activity_syndication_options
bp_activity_filter_options
bp_after_directory_activity_content
bp_before_activity_post_form
bp_activity_post_form_options
bp_after_activity_post_form
bp_before_archive
bp_before_blog_post
bp_after_blog_post
bp_after_archive
bp_before_attachment
bp_before_blog_post
bp_after_blog_post
bp_after_attachment
bp_before_blogs_loop
bp_directory_blogs_item
bp_directory_blogs_actions
bp_after_directory_blogs_list
bp_after_blogs_loop
bp_before_directory_blogs_content
template_notices
bp_before_create_blog_content
bp_after_create_blog_content
bp_after_directory_blogs_content
bp_before_directory_blogs_content
bp_blogs_directory_blog_types
bp_blogs_directory_order_options
bp_after_directory_blogs_content
bp_before_blog_comment_list
bp_after_blog_comment_list
bp_before_blog_comment_form
bp_blog_comment_form
bp_after_blog_comment_form
bp_after_container
bp_before_footer
bp_footer
bp_after_footer
bp_before_directory_forums_list
bp_directory_forums_extra_cell_head
bp_directory_forums_extra_cell
bp_directory_forums_extra_row
bp_after_directory_forums_list
bp_before_directory_forums_content
groups_forum_new_topic_before
groups_forum_new_topic_after
bp_forums_directory_group_types
bp_forums_directory_order_options
bp_directory_forums_content
bp_after_directory_forums_content
bp_before_create_group
template_notices
bp_before_group_details_creation_step
bp_after_group_details_creation_step
bp_before_group_settings_creation_step
bp_after_group_settings_creation_step
bp_before_group_avatar_creation_step
bp_after_group_avatar_creation_step
bp_before_group_invites_creation_step
bp_after_group_invites_creation_step
groups_custom_create_steps
bp_before_group_creation_step_buttons
bp_after_group_creation_step_buttons
bp_directory_groups_content
bp_after_create_group
bp_before_groups_loop
bp_directory_groups_item
bp_directory_groups_actions
bp_after_groups_loop
bp_before_directory_groups_content
bp_groups_directory_group_types
bp_groups_directory_order_options
bp_directory_groups_content
bp_after_directory_groups_content
bp_group_activity_syndication_options
bp_group_activity_filter_options
bp_before_group_activity_post_form
bp_after_group_activity_post_form
bp_before_group_activity_content
bp_after_group_activity_content
bp_before_group_admin_content
bp_before_group_details_admin
groups_custom_group_fields_editable
bp_after_group_details_admin
bp_before_group_settings_admin
bp_after_group_settings_admin
bp_before_group_manage_members_admin
bp_group_manage_members_admin_item
bp_after_group_manage_members_admin
bp_before_group_membership_requests_admin
bp_group_membership_requests_admin_item
bp_group_membership_requests_admin_item_action
bp_after_group_membership_requests_admin
groups_custom_edit_steps
bp_before_group_delete_admin
bp_after_group_delete_admin
bp_after_group_admin_content
bp_before_group_forum_edit_form
bp_group_before_edit_forum_topic
bp_group_after_edit_forum_topic
bp_group_before_edit_forum_post
bp_group_after_edit_forum_post
bp_after_group_forum_edit_form
bp_before_group_forum_topic
bp_group_forum_topic_meta
bp_before_group_forum_topic_posts
bp_group_forum_post_meta
bp_after_group_forum_topic_posts
groups_forum_new_reply_before
groups_forum_new_reply_after
bp_after_group_forum_topic
bp_before_group_forum_content
bp_after_group_forum_content
bp_before_group_forum_post_new
bp_after_group_forum_post_new
bp_before_group_header
bp_after_group_menu_admins
bp_before_group_menu_mods
bp_after_group_menu_mods
bp_before_group_header_meta
bp_group_header_meta
bp_after_group_header
template_notices
bp_before_group_home_content
bp_group_options_nav
bp_before_group_body
bp_before_group_status_message
bp_after_group_status_message
bp_after_group_body
bp_after_group_home_content
bp_before_group_members_content
bp_before_group_members_list
bp_group_members_list_item
bp_group_members_list_item_action
bp_after_group_members_content
bp_before_group_plugin_template
bp_group_plugin_options_nav
bp_before_group_body
bp_template_content
bp_after_group_body
bp_after_group_plugin_template
bp_before_group_request_membership_content
bp_group_request_membership_content
bp_after_group_request_membership_content
bp_before_group_send_invites_content
bp_before_group_send_invites_list
bp_group_send_invites_item
bp_group_send_invites_item_action
bp_after_group_send_invites_list
bp_after_group_send_invites_content
bp_head
bp_before_header
bp_nav_items
bp_search_login_bar
bp_header
bp_after_header
bp_before_container
bp_before_blog_home
bp_before_blog_post
bp_after_blog_post
bp_after_blog_home
bp_before_blog_links
bp_after_blog_links
bp_before_directory_members_content
bp_members_directory_member_types
bp_members_directory_order_options
bp_directory_members_content
bp_after_directory_members_content
bp_before_members_loop
bp_before_directory_members_list
bp_directory_members_item
bp_directory_members_actions
bp_after_directory_members_list
bp_after_members_loop
bp_member_activity_filter_options
bp_before_member_activity_post_form
bp_after_member_activity_post_form
bp_before_member_activity_content
bp_after_member_activity_content
bp_member_blog_order_options
bp_before_member_blogs_content
bp_after_member_blogs_content
bp_before_member_friend_requests_content
bp_friend_requests_item
bp_friend_requests_item_action
bp_friend_requests_content
bp_after_member_friend_requests_content
bp_member_blog_order_options
bp_before_member_friends_content
bp_after_member_friends_content
bp_before_group_invites_content
bp_group_invites_item
bp_group_invites_item_action
bp_after_group_invites_content
bp_member_group_order_options
bp_before_member_groups_content
bp_after_member_groups_content
bp_before_member_home_content
bp_member_options_nav
bp_before_member_body
bp_after_member_body
bp_after_member_home_content
bp_before_member_header
bp_before_member_header_meta
bp_profile_header_meta
bp_after_member_header
template_notices
bp_before_messages_compose_content
bp_after_messages_compose_content
bp_before_member_messages_loop
bp_after_member_messages_pagination
bp_before_member_messages_threads
bp_messages_inbox_list_item
bp_after_member_messages_threads
bp_after_member_messages_options
bp_after_member_messages_loop
bp_before_notices_loop
bp_after_notices_pagination
bp_before_notices
bp_notices_list_item
bp_after_notices
bp_after_notices_loop
bp_before_message_thread_content
bp_before_message_thread_list
bp_before_message_meta
bp_after_message_meta
bp_before_message_content
bp_after_message_content
bp_after_message_thread_list
bp_before_message_thread_reply
bp_before_message_meta
bp_after_message_meta
bp_before_message_reply_box
bp_after_message_reply_box
bp_after_message_thread_reply
bp_after_message_thread_content
bp_before_member_messages_content
bp_after_member_messages_content
bp_before_member_plugin_template
bp_member_options_nav
bp_before_member_body
bp_member_plugin_options_nav
bp_template_title
bp_template_content
bp_after_member_body
bp_after_member_plugin_template
bp_before_profile_avatar_upload_content
bp_after_profile_avatar_upload_content
bp_before_profile_edit_content
bp_before_profile_field_content
bp_custom_profile_edit_fields
bp_after_profile_field_content
bp_after_profile_edit_content
bp_before_profile_loop_content
bp_before_profile_field_content
bp_profile_field_item
bp_after_profile_field_content
bp_profile_field_buttons
bp_after_profile_loop_content
bp_before_profile_content
bp_after_profile_content
bp_before_blog_page
bp_after_blog_page
bp_before_activation_page
template_notices
bp_before_activate_content
bp_after_activate_content
bp_after_activation_page
bp_before_register_page
template_notices
bp_before_account_details_fields
bp_signup_username_errors
bp_signup_email_errors
bp_signup_password_errors
bp_signup_password_confirm_errors
bp_after_account_details_fields
bp_before_signup_profile_fields
bp_custom_profile_edit_fields
bp_after_signup_profile_fields
bp_before_blog_details_fields
bp_signup_blog_url_errors
bp_signup_blog_title_errors
bp_signup_blog_privacy_errors
bp_after_blog_details_fields
bp_before_registration_submit_buttons
bp_after_registration_submit_buttons
template_notices
bp_custom_signup_steps
bp_after_register_page
bp_after_directory_activity_content
bp_before_blog_search
bp_before_blog_post
bp_after_blog_post
bp_after_blog_search
bp_before_blog_search_form
bp_blog_search_form
bp_after_blog_search_form
bp_before_sidebar
bp_inside_before_sidebar
bp_before_sidebar_me
bp_sidebar_me
bp_after_sidebar_me
bp_before_sidebar_login_form
bp_sidebar_login_form
bp_after_sidebar_login_form
bp_inside_after_sidebar
bp_after_sidebar
bp_before_blog_single_post
bp_after_blog_single_post
xprofile_profile_group_tabs
xprofile_install
xprofile_setup_globals
xprofile_setup_nav
xprofile_adminbar_menu_items
xprofile_screen_edit_profile
xprofile_avatar_uploaded
xprofile_screen_change_avatar
xprofile_register_activity_actions
```

Comment: This is awesome.... but Deryk i am new to buddypress so i want to study or to understand the use of these hooks. So i can place it in correct place....anyhow thanks...

Comment: the best thing to do is to read the code itself. The BuddyPress codex is growing, but it's not a strong as the WordPress codex. and even with wordpress it's often best to just read the code. One thing I've found incredibly helpful is to have a real IDE. I was using Coda in the past, but it's mainly for html/css. Now I use PHPStorm and love it. Just Cmd click a function and boom, your're there at the function itself.

Comment: this seems to be missing a few, could you run it with `apply_filters` too?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

http://byotos.wordpress.com/2010/02/07/how-to-get-a-list-of-buddypress-actions/

Comment: thanks...but i doesn't use (on Mac or Linux). As i am expecting like wordpress codex...

Comment: You're sort of sh*t out of luck then, sorry :/ From what I understand this is the single best source.

Comment: Yes i understand..but i am looking for complete documentation for hooks and functions.. Anyhow thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress spoils you for by the amount of documentation that it provides. Not many applications can boast the level of documentation that wordpress provides.

That being said there is not better way to learn than digging down and looking through the core files. Buddypress is opensource so you have access to all the source code which you can use to work out what all the hooks do

just do a search for bp_directory_groups_search_form() within the plugin directory and start to follow the code trail.

It might be a bit harder to crack at first but once you start to understand how it works you become less reliant on codex etc learn a heap at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There is http://codex.buddypress.org/, but it certainly isn't the codex you have in mind. However, there is some documentation there so perhaps it will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

There still isn't a proper hook reference to date and the most likely reason being that the BuddyPress team have their hands full building the platform. We the users need to take up the challenge and see about bringing the documentation up to speed.

As for OP's question, I did an [output of the hook call-chain](http://codex.buddypress.org/developer/buddypress-action-hook-sequence-during-startup/) during the startup of a BuddyPress (1.9) install on WordPress 3.8. It's by no means a complete listing of all the hooks, but does show the order in which the hooks are called so it's easier to figure out where to register your plugin/theme callbacks. The BuddyPress hooks are prefixed with **bp_**